# Computer won't boot with DVI monitor plugged in

Tags: boot, graphics-card, dvi

I am having an issue with my Dell Inspiron 660.
It has an AMD Radeon HD 6570 graphics card with a monitor connected via the DVI port.

The problem is, the computer won't boot with the monitor plugged in.  If I reboot the computer, or just power it up, the monitor will not activate (the power light blinks in stand-by mode), and the computer will not even attempt to boot.  Only the fans will come on.  If I press the power button on the computer, it will turn off immediately.

I finally figured out that if I *unplug* the cable from the DVI monitor (not just turn it off) and then plug in a VGA monitor, the computer will boot normally.  Once it's booted I can unplug the VGA monitor and plug the DVI monitor back in and everything will be fine.

This is a real hassle since I have to keep a separate monitor on hand sitting by my desk every time I want to reboot, or boot up the computer.

The BIOS is also extremely limited and has no options for graphics that I can find.  Also, it has a new 500W power supply, so it has plenty of juice.

Any thoughts or guidance on how to deal with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Are you using the latest BIOS? Using the latest drivers for the graphics card? Has this configuration ever worked properly? Or is this a new setup?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. 
I didn't think about updating the BIOS (I've never updated one before). I'll give that a try.
The graphics drivers are the most recent, I updated them a few days ago.
I don't remember if it ever did work correctly.  I installed the graphics card probably a year or two ago. It's been a hassle for a long time and it's just something where we've avoided resetting the computer unless absolutely necessary.
Recently just completely wiped the harddrive, partitions, etc. and reinstalled the operating system, and no change.